# IE 10+ specific css rules not taking precedence in IE

Tags: css

According to this answer, the following can be used to target IE10 and IE11:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  /* css specific to IE10 and IE11
}
```

So I'm my css file, I've got a rule, such as the following.

```
.bigbox {
display: flex;
}
```

As I don't want IE to flex this box, I've got the following BELOW the initial declaration:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  .bigbox {
  display: default;
   }

}
```

When I inspect the div using the developer tool in IE, I can see that IE11 sees both rules, but it gives the non-IE specific rule priority and, as a result, flexs the box. Why does it do this? Is there a way to prevent this?

I've even set the IE declaration to !important and that does nothing either.

Thanks!

Comment: [Because there is no `display: default`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Used block. Worked 100% :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There's no such thing as "display: default".**

Try "display: initial;" or something more fitting (inline, block).

//EDIT:
See here for reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: Used block. Worked! Thank you!

Comment: @JasonHoward Would you be so kind and accept the answer then?